# Laravel 4: Unable to generate a URL for the named route "login" as such route does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm creating an authorization system in my Laravel 4 project.  I am trying to use the auth "before" filter.

In my `routes.php` file, I have:

```php
Route::get('viewer', array('before' => 'auth', function() {
    return View::make('lead_viewer');
}));

Route::get('login', 'LoginController');
```

The before filter calls this line in the `filters.php` file:

```php
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::route('login');
});
```

I can manually navigate to my login route.  But the auth system isn't letting this happen.  I've run `composer dump-autoload` a couple of times, so that isn't the problem.  What am I doing, since I can actually load the login page if I do it manually?

Answer (score 6):

I figure it out.  Laravel is looking for a named route:  I had to do this:

```php
Route::get('login', array('as' => 'login', function() {
    return View::make('login');
}));
```

An interesting, not very intuitive approach in Laravel.  But there must be a reason Taylor did this that I'm not seeing.

Comment: I think Taylor made it a named route to give us more flexibility. Since its named, you can have your actual route be whatever you want, rather than forcing us to use "login" or having to change the source for the 'auth' filter.

Comment: Yeah took me a while to figure that out.

Answer (score 2):

To do what you were trying to do in your initial approach you could have just done:

```php
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::to('/login');
});
```

and it would have worked just fine.

If you want to use named routes then you do what you posted in your answer to your own question. Essentially...more than one way to skin a cat.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I know you've probably solved this by now but after stumbling across your post while trying to solve a similar problem, I wanted to share my thoughts...

Laravel is **NOT** looking for a named route for the guest method, it is expecting a **path**.

Your example works because because the named route and the path are the same i.e. "login".  Try changing your URL to something other than 'login' and watch it fail.

If you want to use a named route you should use the route helper method as so...

```
if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest( route('login') )
```

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Was driving me nuts. Thank you.